# Problems with .pdf-files in Joomla 1.6

Tags: .htaccess, pdf, joomla, http-status-code-403, joomla1.6

I've installed a Joomla 1.6 template, and everything is working fine except 1 thing.

I have uploaded some .pdf-files somewhere in the file system and people who visit the site can view or download these pdf-files, but when I click on the link or trying to right-click and "Save as target" I get an error message like this:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   /path/filename.pdf on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.6
>   mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server
>   at *website* Port 80

I've logged in as administrator and checked if I found anything that denies access to files with .pdf extension, but all I found was that it seems like a .htaccess-file is being created in the same folder as the .pdf-files just after I'm trying to open them in my browser.

The content of the .htaccess file that is being created is this:

```
deny from all
```

I have also tried to edit this files content to "allow from all", and tried to delete it too, but Joomla is just changing it back.

Anyone know why or what that prevents me from viewing or downloading the pdf-files?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a server setting?  I've never had that issue with any Joomla installation I've made.  Are you placing the .pdf's in a directory that is typically a bad idea (i.e. in the administration area, etc) ?

Comment: Yeah, I also think it's some server setting or some setting that can be changed in the Joomla admin-panel, but can't find such settings.
Also, I'm placing the .pdf's in a subfolder of the images-folder, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Yea, hearing that makes me think it's a server setting somewhere.  As I said, I've done a lot of that sort of thing with various Joomla installs but never ran into that issue.  Definitely not a 'default' joomla reaction to having a few .pdf's in a folder.  That said, I don't know what server setting it might be.  I'm not much help there, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

If it's a UNIX/Linux server you can FTP in with a client that shows permissions like FileZilla. It's probably the permissions associated with the parent folder cascading down to these files. Try to see if you can upload an image to the images folder and if you can save it the same way you're trying to save the PDFs. If downloading the image to your machine works, I would then look at the permissions settings. If you're not sure which permissions to look for, check out this: http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html

Usually a client can download/view files with permissions of 644 or higher.

Comment: I have checked the folder permissions and all has 644 or higher. The problem is that a .htaccess file is being created in the same folder as the .pdf's that has "deny from all", which means that no-one has access to the files in that folder.

However, as explained in the original text, I'm not sure about what is creating the .htaccess-file (it seems it's something either on the server or some settings that can be changed in the Joomla Administration-panel).

Comment: It's worth a try to disable all of the plugins that you currently have installed. You could also change your .htaccess and lock down the permissions so it absolutely can't be changed by anyone.

Comment: I've never seen a plugin that would go outside of it's own folders and insert a .htaccess file anywhere.  I think taking the time to disable every plugin would be kind of pointless IMO as it definitely sounds like a server setting somewhere.  It's something to try - but I think it should be considered a later option to try.